# Creating foreign key in phpmyadmin mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Creating a comment system with a simple rating system for each comment.

tables :  1.For the comments and it is called `comments` and it has three columns : `id`, `name`, `comment`
2. for the IP of the user that did the rating and it is called `voted_ip`and it has three columns `id`, `comment_id`, `user_ip`

The purpose of the voted_ip table is that i need to save the IP address for each rate to validate it that it cannot rate again if it exists.

I created a foreign key from the child table `voted_ip` in the column `comment_id` connecting it to the parent table `comments` in the column `id` following the steps at this [link](http://www.elitetechnologygroup.com/welcome/index.php?view=entry&year=2010&month=02&day=16&id=16:phpmyadmin-relational-tables-wforeign-keys&option=com_lyftenbloggie) and this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3xvwhqYYMQ) on how to create a working foreign key except that the child table still do not update after a comment or a rate is inserted.

as follow : [image: the foreign key creation]

I thought about that there might be another step or I have to do something in the php side of the project. What am I missing?

Comment: Post the schemas and the query.

Comment: Just so simple I did not write any queries I shared a screenshot though

Comment: If it is really so simple, then how come that you have a question here?

Comment: That video link helped me! I was looking where relations are defined!

Answer (score 2):

Data is not inserted in the other table "voted_ip" on insertion in "comment" by itself you have to add it explicitly this constraints are just for checking not for adding data in other table automatically.